# Two music streams in one session

Tags: linux, audio

I have been trying to see if I can make the following work in linux (technically, Redhat/Centos or even Fedora): I want my system sounds to be sent to my speakers. I want my music to be sent to my headphones. I can set system sounds to use one instance of PulseAudio or Alsa. I can set my music player to use a completely separate instance of PulseAudio or Alsa. Then, I can use the audio mixer to direct each instance to the proper output. However, only the last one I set works. I assume it is a hardware limitation, but I wanted to know if there is a software reason it isn't working.